# AOSP Messaging Layout with Data within TabView

Tags: android, angular, android-source, nativescript, tabview

Guys I've been looking around for the answer to wrap this layout within tabview but it seems there was nothing out there so I'm asking here hopefully someone could shed some lights.

What I encountered: I wanted to wrap the AOSP messaging layout suggested on NS snacks [http://www.nativescriptsnacks.com/snippets/2016/08/30/AOSP-messaging-layout.html] with fake conversation data, using the fake library as a dependency, passing through a service within the default tabview for an Android app however nothing was shown in the view when running.

Here're the files, first **conversation.ts** containing classes for maintainability:

```
export class User {
  name: string;
  pictureUrl: string;
}

export class Conversation {
  sender: User;
  content: string;
  date: Date;
}

export class Participants {
  me: User;
  other: User;
}

export class Convo {
  participants: Participants;
  conversations: Array<Conversation>;
}
```

**conversation.service.ts** with faker library and content configurations:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { User, Conversation, Participants, Convo } from "./conversation";
const faker = require("faker");

@Injectable()
export class ConversationService {

  getConvo(): Convo {
    const me = {
      name: "Me",
      pictureUrl: "https://unsplash.it/100/100?image=790"
    };
    const other = {
      name: faker.name.findName(),
      pictureUrl: "https://unsplash.it/100/100?image=823"
    };

    const conversations = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      const sender = faker.random.boolean() ? me : other;
      const content = faker.lorem.sentence();
      const date = faker.date.recent();

      conversations.push({
        sender: sender,
        content: content,
        date: date
      });
    }

    const convo = {
      participants: {
        me: me,
        other: other
      },
      conversations: conversations.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.date - b.date;
      })
    };

    return convo;
  }
}
```

The **conversation.component.ts**, importing the previous two files:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ConversationService } from "../../shared/conversation/conversation.service";
import { User, Conversation } from "../../shared/conversation/conversation";
/*
import { NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from "nativescript-angular/router";
*/

@Component({
  selector: "conversation",
  providers: [ConversationService],
  // directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: "views/views.html", // Linking directly to the tabview
})
export class ConversationComponent implements OnInit {
  public me: User;
  public other: User;
  public conversations: Array<Conversation>;
  public tabIndex: number;

    constructor(private conversationService: ConversationService) {
      const convo = conversationService.getConvo();

      this.me = convo.participants.me;
      this.other = convo.participants.other;
      this.conversations = convo.conversations;
      this.tabIndex = 0; // To be the landing tab
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      // Setting properties in page class
      // this.getConvo();
    }  

    /*
    getConvo() {
      this.conversationService.getConvo().then((conversations) => {
        this.conversations = conversations
      }).catch(function(error) {
        global.tnsconsole.error('error', error)
      })
    }
    */
}
```

A note here I've imitated the typescript setup in the AOSP layout though not quite sure how to truly go about it. There's that importing object

> { NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }

I couldn't find in local nativescript-angular/router folder nor I had any idea about how to. Where does one get { NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from?

The template **views.html** of the tabview, to show the conversation component and others, referencing the linked AOSP layout:

```
<TabView #tabView [selectedIndex]="tabIndex">

  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Conversation'}">
    <ActionBar title="Conversation">
      <ActionItem text="Menu" android.position="popup"></ActionItem>
    </ActionBar>

    <ListView class="threads-list" [items]="conversations">
      <template let-item="item">
        <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="auto,*" class="threads-wrapper">
          <Image row="0" col="0" [src]="item.sender.pictureUrl"></Image>
          <StackLayout row="0" col="1" orientation="vertical">
            <Label [text]="item.sender.name" class="item-title"></Label>
            <Label [text]="item.content"></Label>
            <Label [text]="item.date" class="convo-date"></Label>
          </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
      </template>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>

  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Tab Title'}">
    <Label text="Content to display"></Label>
  </StackLayout>

</TabView>
```

**views.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "views",
  templateUrl: "views/views.html"
})
export class ViewsComponent {
}
```

How do I get the conversation data displayed on the view wrapped within the tabview? My template in app.component.ts is < page-router-outlet >< /page-router-outlet >.

The above configurations show data without the tabview however not otherwise.

Any updated info about the AOSP layout would be appreciated.

Comment: NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES is now deprecated as NativeScript has implemented the latest version of Angular router https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes

Comment: The documentation article about navigation can help a lot to change this implementation https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation.html